# Удалить метку [bugs]?

Tags: обсуждение, метки, удаление-метки

Метка: [bugs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bugs). Буквально метка «обо всём». Синонимом
ни к чему не прикрепишь. Если можно забанить,
было бы совсем хорошо, как мне
кажется. Что скажет сообщество?

Comment: Согласен, надо удалить

Comment: [вот пример занятного употребления этой метки](https://stackoverflow.com/cv/chabanovsky)

Comment: Странная вообще метка. О чём? "Я нашёл багу"? ну-ну... 99.(9)% что это не так. "Я эксплуатирую документированную багу аки фичу"? ну bad pratice и ССЗБ. bugfix? во-первых, сильно смахивает на неформат, во-вторых, именно bugfix разумнее...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Снес метку [bugs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bugs)

Вот только думаю может скоро появиться снова...

Comment: Не все ж снесли, 5 вопросов осталось, вот например: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/583297/Рабочий-процесс-workflow-когда-надо-поддерживать-много-веток-исходного-кода Походу поиск глючит, через раз выдает что 0 результатов, хотя они есть.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Спасибо, а мне показывало, что нет... Ну теперь точно готово! ;)